# Turbo c++ debugging issue

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I am developing a small app in c using turbo c++ IDE.

I defined required constants in header file and included in the source with include directive.
I created a project by adding source file.

But while debugging,when i add a header file constant to watch window,it is showing 'undefined symbol'.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "constant"? Do you mean `const` qualified object or a `#define` macro? The first shouldn't be defined in a header file, the 2nd is 'deleted' by the compilation process.

Comment: **Don't use TurboC++.** It is a compiler for an *obsolete* programming language. Use [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (or C++14 or C++17) or [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) (or C11) standard conforming compilers such as recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). You'll find many source code editors -e.g. `emacs`  or `vim`- (and build automation tools -e.g. GNU `make`) to use with them

Comment: Dear @pmg,I defined constant like '#define X_CNST 2'. What is the reason that 'X_CNST' is deleted by compiler?. Generally it is recommended to use header files to define constant values i think.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Without source code (and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) your question is too broad and off-topic. So please **edit your question** to show source code (with four spaces before every line). Don't comment your own question (but improve it by editing it)

Comment: Yes, @ramus, constants created with `#define` belong in header files. But they never survive through the compilation process: see my answer.

Comment: Dear @Basile Starynkevitch,  I need a small 16 bit app for my small academic project.By the way do you mean 'C' is obsolete programming language?

Comment: Dear @pmg,thank you. So to see if constant is correctly applied i need to use it in an expression and assign the result to a variable and check variable in watch window?.

Comment: even if it's small, it'll be better be written in a standard compiler ([Turbo C++ is not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1961828/995714)). Performance will also be better because modern compilers are much better at optimization

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Macros always work well; your problem lies elsewhere. Show your code, the macro definition, the way you are using it, tell us what you expected to happen and what really happened. Maybe you need parenthesis around the whole macro? `#define FOO ( big*ugly*mess )`

Comment: Dear @pmg,my purpose is to test constant value defined in header file is correctly applied.Your answer post really helped understand how compilation works.Thanks again

Comment: Hey @ramus, what kind of pc and os are you using with TurboC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Phase 4 of the compilation process](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) effectively removes any `#define`

```
#define FOO 42
/* ... */
int a = FOO;
```

after phase 4 becomes

```
/* ... comment deleted in phase 3 */
int a = 42;
```

There is no `FOO` symbol in the produced executable.